# One-to-Many relationship mapping returns validation errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping

Edited with the new situation per suggestion in the comments:

Currently I have this mapping

```
public ShowMap() {
        ToTable("Shows");
        HasKey(x => x.ShowID);

        Property(x => x.ShowID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("ShowID");
}

public EpisodeMap() {
        ToTable("Episodes");
        HasKey(x => x.EpisodeID);

        Property(x => x.EpisodeID)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
        .HasColumnName("EpisodeID");

        Property(x => x.ShowID)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("ShowID");

        Property(x => x.EpisodeNumber)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("EpisodeNumber");
}
```

This results in the following database:

[image: Episodes]

[image: Shows]

However, when the seed method is run I receive this error. Since I can't debug the value of variables from the command line command `Update-Database` (at least, not as far as I know) I can't see what the property holds.

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

When I add the relationship to the mapping, I receive the following error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Episode_Show_Source' in relationship 'Episode_Show'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.

Relationship:

```
        HasRequired(x => x.Show)
            .WithMany(x => x.Episodes)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.EpisodeID);
```

This is the model:

```
public class Episode {
  public int EpisodeID {get; set;}
  public int ShowID {get; set;}
  public int EpisodeNumber {get; set;}
  public virtual Show Show { get; set; }
}

public class Show {
  public int ShowID {get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Episode> Episodes { get; set; }
}
```

What have I overlooked that causes validation errors?

Edit: just to be certain I haven't forgotten anything, [this](https://github.com/Vannevelj/NoName/tree/master/NoName/NoName) is the project on github.

Comment: Why the need to have an compmosite key? new { x.ParentID, x.ChildID }) Is uniqueness only established by this table having both keys present?

Comment: The uniqueness of a record in the Child table is determined by the ParentID and a ChildID. The real world usage applicable here is a Show and its episodes: A show has multiple episodes, but each episode only belongs to one show. Would you suggest a different approach?

Comment: Essentially it looks like you are telling EF to map ChildId twice, as a composite key and as a FK. Remove the ChildId and Parent id from the POCO. EF can figure that out. And if possible declare a unique single PK on Child (entity seed) to not have to use a composite.

Comment: I have refactored my program, but the error persists. I have updated the post to reflect the changes.

Comment: Is this really *exactly* your model and mapping? That's a standard one-to-many relationship that everyone has used a hundred times without problems. The exception makes no sense at all.

Comment: I looked over everything I posted here and couldn't find a difference. Just to be sure I have edited my post with the link to the github project since it might bring something to light that I forgot to include.

Comment: In your public class Episode what is virtual Show Show for? Is it a pointer back to the public class Show? If it is, you shouldn't need it because you have the relationship established with ShowID.

Comment: Yes. I'd like to be able to access the properties of a show from an episode.

Comment: What do you mean? Should I just leave it out? How would I access the show's properties then?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the problem (from your git repository, class `EpisodeMap`):

```
HasRequired(x => x.Show)
    .WithMany(x => x.Episodes)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.EpisodeID);
```

`EpisodeID` is the PK in `Episode` and EF expects a one-to-one mapping in this case without an `Episodes` collection but an `Episode` reference instead ("upper bound of multiplicity = 1").

For a one-to-many relationship it has to be:

```
HasRequired(x => x.Show)
    .WithMany(x => x.Episodes)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ShowID);
```

Comment: That did indeed solve the relationship related error, thanks! I've changed it and now the tables are created again. I still receive the entity validation error on the seed method though (Github: https://github.com/Vannevelj/NoName/blob/master/NoName/NoName/Migrations/Configuration.cs)

Comment: Solved! The error was as it said: a validationerror. I've gone over my test data and the mapping and noticed the maxlength of one of the properties is 128. The seed data contained way more than that, setting it to 1028 solved the problem and I received my testing data.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Just as a tip for the next time when you can't debug the validation errors: Call `SaveChanges` at the end of the Seed method manually in a try-catch block and write the errors into a file, like shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16619043/270591

Comment: Very good idea, I'll add this to my project. In retrospect, the error message actually told me what was wrong, I should've found it way sooner.

Comment: For my E-R model I didn't have the field at all corresponding to your `ShowID` field in my POCO classes. I was using code first development approach. It works. I was under an impression that fluent configuration APIs will be able to achieve it on its own while creating the database for the first time.