# Updating EF model created using code first approach

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am working on a project that uses EF created with code first approach. The model was created by someone else. In the database table there was no primary key and all the fields were mandatory. Now we need a column to be auto incremented primary key and another column to be optional. We have made these changes in the database table but we are getting 'Entity Validation Error' since we are not passing the "ID"(probably the reason). What are the changes and where should they be written? Here is the class that was created:

```
public int ID { get; set; }//This needs to be auto incremented primary key.
public int UserID{ get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
public bool Deleted { get; set; }
public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
public System.DateTime DateModified { get; set; }//This field needs to be optional.
```

Comment: How are you updating edmx ?

Comment: There is no edmx in my solution.

Comment: Switching identity on and off is not trivial. You may need to drop and recreate the table. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18917348/150342

Comment: Did you tried to rename UserID to something else for example CurrentUserID; the problem ID and UserID is a vaild primery key for this class and I think this class is called User.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Key and DatabaseGenerated attributes for the new Id Property.

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

Comment: I have already tried that. I am still getting the error: "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details"

Comment: Can you catch the DbEntityValidationException and see what is present in the list of errors?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7798264/1305119

Comment: I can't hit the debugger because I am using ASP.Net Web API controller.

Comment: Then you can write the exception to a file....http://stackoverflow.com/a/16619043/1305119

Comment: I made both the projects as start up project to enable debugging. I could get the exception. The inner exception states "Can not insert NULL into column ID". This is my primary key column that I need to be auto incremented and identity.